# How to apply this data into flutter API?

Tags: flutter

- Api Paramter:

> Send below values in request in "getProducts"
> whats new:- sort_by: product_id, sort_order: desc
> Price- High to Low:- sort_by: price, sort_order: desc
> Price- Low to high:- sort_by: price, sort_order: asc
> New to Old:- sort_by: product_id, sort_order: desc
> Old to new:- sort_by: product_id, sort_order: asc
> Discount:- sort_by: discount, sort_order: desc

Comment: be explicit. what do you want to do?

Comment: i have to sort data using this api..and how to used this api in dio?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code try that :-

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as HTTP;
import 'dart:convert';
class API {
//replace with your endpoint
 static String BASE_URL = 'https://some-url/api/';

static Future<List<ExampleData>> getRequest() async {

Response res = await http.get(BASE_URL+'example');

  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
  List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(res.body);
  //sort it here if you want
    
 // complete by parsing the json body return into ExampleData object and 
  return 'Your data';

  }
} 
}
```